# No PostgreSQL, há diferença entre se executar um dump ou fazer uma exportação?

Tags: postgresql, backup

esta pergunta realmente me deixou em dúvida, pois no postgres há três tipos de backup/restore que são:

1. SQL Dump (Gera um arquivo texto com comando SQL)
2. File System Level Backup (Salvar o arquivo de dados do PG)
3. Continuous Archiving (Backup através do LOG)

Gostaria de saber se estas formas são tratados como dump ou/e exportação?

Answer (score 2):

Olá DiegoSoaresSub o mais adequado sem dúvida é o SQL Dump por gerar de forma otimizada uma copia do seu banco(s) que fácilmente pode ser importado para outras máquinas ou servidores. Veja que o File System Level tem uma série de restrições ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup-file.html ) que se não tomar cuidado pode não ser possível gerar uma cópia fiel por exemplo. Por fim o Continuous Archiving exige que seja ativado o recurso antes para que se possa recuperar independentemente de se fazer um dump ou não, mas é necessário estar consciente que isso exige armazenamento e processamento extra de forma contínua ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup-online.html ) .

Answer (score 1):

As três formas servem de alguma forma para backup.

**SQL Dump** é o modo mais flexível, porém o arquivo texto pode ficar muito grande na medida em que o banco cresce. Para importação e exportação parcial, considere o comando [**`COPY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html), o qual permite exportação usando `SELECT`.

***File System Level Backup*** é melhor do ponto de vista de administrador de sistemas, por ser apenas uma cópia de arquivos do sistema. Porém, o processo do banco de dados precisa ser devidamente encerrado para garantir que todas as informações estão devidamente atualizadas. Uma cópia a qualquer momento pode gerar um backup corrompido ou com dados parciais (que estão sendo gravados naquele momento).

Uma forma melhor de fazer backup dos arquivos sem precisar parar o processo é usando o comando [`pg_basebackup`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgbasebackup.html). Ele garante que o arquivo copiado está íntegro e atualizado.

***Continuous Archiving*** é a forma mais rígida de backup. Ele permite restaurar o estado do banco em qualquer ponto no tempo. Porém, vai consumir muitos recursos como espaço em disco e tempo de gravação de dados, gerando logs de informações extensos. Para restaurar um determinado estado é necessário ter os logs desde o último backup realizado até aquele ponto.

Técnicas como o "Arquivamento Contínuo" geralmente são usadas de forma mista com backups normais. Enquanto o backup garante a recuperação de dados completa em intervalos de tempo pré-definidos, o *Continuous Archiving* garante a recuperação em praticamente qualquer momento.

É importante notar que arquivos binários copiados diretamente ou gerados pelo `COPY` podem ser dependentes da versão do PostgreSQL. Arquivos texto, por outro lado, costumam ser independentes de versão.