# Espelhamento de Banco de Dados

Tags: java, postgresql

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicação em `Java` utilizando banco de dados `PostgreSQL`, localmente. Bem gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de espelhar esse meu banco local para um servidor externo?

Existe alguma API em `Java` para isso?

Se puderem me ajudar, eu realmente agradeço muito.

Comment: espelhamento refere-se a exportar a base de dados local para um servidor?

Comment: Por exemplo, no meu banco local tenho 30 novos registros. Em certo momento quero espelhar esses novos registros para meu banco externo.

Comment: O melhor método de sincronização de dados depende muito do resultado esperado, do tipo de sistema e dos dados, além da infraestrutura disponível em ambos os lados. Sugiro explicar a finalidade desse processo. Por exemplo, se for para backup existem determinadas alternativas (]ver minha resposta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36716/227)); se for para enviar certos registros cadastrados daria para colocar os itens numa fila e enviar de forma assíncrona usando qualquer tecnologia que quiser; e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1):

O processo de sincronização de dados entre instâncias diferentes do SGBD pode ser feito de diversas formas, mas geralmente através de um processo conhecido como replicação.

Existem diversos produtos que proveem sólida plataforma para replicação, alguns gratuitos, outros pagos. O mais importante é entender o motivador dessa necessidade, para então entender qual arquitetura atenderia sua necessidade.

De maneira geral, escrever um programa Java para replicar dados entre servidores deve ser a solução escolhida somente se nenhuma alternativa disponível solucionar seu problema.